# I want to repeat row after 2 columns where datas are retrieved dynamically in php

Tags: php, html

Upon doing this I am gating the data in an un alligned manner. I am getting 2 datas but the third data is coming under second data and 4th below first data but 3rd and forth are not in a single row there placed one after the other.

My View

```
<div class="container col-md-9"> 

        <?php
            foreach($unidet as $tempuni)
            { 
        ?>

            <div class="service-items col-md-6">
                <h4 class="title-normal"><img class="img-responsive thumb" src="images/service/service-icon1.png" alt=""><strong><?php echo $tempuni['name'] ?></strong></h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 service-item-img">
                   <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="admin/<?php echo $tempuni['image'];?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 service-item-content">
                        <p><?php  echo $tempuni['description'];?></p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="more(<?php echo $tempuni['id'];?>)">Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        <?php
            }
            ?>

            </div>
```

This is what I am getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution would be to use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($unidet, 2) as $row): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($row as $tempuni): ?>
            <div class="service-items col-md-6">
                <h4 class="title-normal"><img class="img-responsive thumb" src="images/service/service-icon1.png" alt=""><strong><?php echo $tempuni['name'] ?></strong></h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 service-item-img">
                        <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="admin/<?php echo $tempuni['image'];?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 service-item-content">
                        <p><?php  echo $tempuni['description'];?></p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="more(<?php echo $tempuni['id'];?>)">Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```